# Running Job and Paused Job Writing to the same File

Tags: tcpdump, zsh, job-control

So I ran tcpdump twice overnight by accident, both outputting to the same file.  However, I ran them as jobs and one of them has been paused the whole time.  Anyone have a recommendations on how to keep the file? So far I have thought of:

1. `kill -9` the paused job
2. Pause the running job, copy the file, and then stop both.

Two sounds like the safest option, anyone have a better idea other than not doing this in the first place ;-)

Comment: I vote for option #2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make a backup of the file just in case, better to be safe than sorry!